Hello this message keeps showing up to me when I do a test When creating the application and for information I use the Android application codeassist
WARNING: Unrecognized file
generated-rules.txt
WARNING: Unrecognized file R.txt
ERROR: attribute emojiconSize (aka com.ai.emojiworkshopnew:emojiconSize) not found. [activity_main.xml:9]
ERROR: attribute lottie_autoPlay (aka com.ai.emojiworkshopnew:lottie_autoPlay) not found. [activity_main.xml:16]
ERROR: attribute lottie_fileName (aka com.ai.emojiworkshopnew:lottie_fileName) not found. [activity_main.xml:16]
ERROR: attribute lottie_loop (aka
com.ai.emojiworkshopnew:lottie_loop) not found. [activity_main.xml:16] ERROR: attribute lottie_speed (aka
com.ai.emojiworkshopnew:lottie_speed) not
found. [activity_main.xml:16]
ERROR: error: failed linking file resources.
ERROR: Compilation failed, check logs for more details.
I tried many ways and did not find a solution. Can anyone help me?
